# Is there any research on allocating memory across multiple non-contiguous regions?

Tags: reference-request, computer-architecture, memory-management

From my understanding, `malloc` and-the-like allocate *contiguous* blocks of memory. It then returns to you the *start address* of the memory block.

This (and other things) leads to memory fragmentation where, after allocating/freeing many times, you have holes where there is unused memory that can't be accessed.

I am imagining that one way to mitigate this problem is to have `malloc` return not just a single address, but an array of addresses and sizes for each address. So it would give you back several *non-contiguous* regions of memory, linked together which for all intents and purposes would *feel* like a single piece of memory, or you could treat it as such (for example, having arrays use this system).

Does any language or system do anything like this? Has anyone researched this? If not, why not? What are the potential problems with this approach?

Comment: I am not aware of any runtime environment that natively implements this sort of two-level indirection (pointer to an array of pointers to memory blocks, abstracted to the program as contiguous memory) for heap allocations. However, on a larger scale, this is exactly what [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) does.